# How to set fixed framerate for opengl android 1.6 (API 4) application?

Tags: android, opengl-es

My render code is written in C++, I am targeting android 1.6. I feel I need to write some Java code to achive fixed framerate. Please do not flame about the fact that fixed framerate is bad, I know that. I need it for special app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it explicitly.
You should rely on some dt-processing logic.